# ul li selector doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue using jquery. I have a content that have to become visible when I click on ul li in navigation.

But I'm missing something, when I click, nothing happens. I am not sure why this happens. Please take a look at the provided fiddle near the bottom

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("ul.topnav > li.one").click(function() {
        $('.content').hide(500).fadeOut(400);
        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
            $(this).next().show(400).fadeIn(500);
        } 
    });

    $('.content').hide();
});
```

```html
<ul class="topnav">
    <li class="one"><a href="#">test</a></li>
    <li>second</li>
</ul>

<div class="content">Some content here</div>
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2pBge/

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle? What behaviour are you expecting to see?

Comment: Did you include jquery on your page? Also `if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true)` can just be `if($(this).next().is(':hidden'))` Also what is the actual issue?

Comment: Why fading out an element already hidden??? The same for fadeIn/show? This doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Your `.next()` is not the content div, it's the second li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

http://jsfiddle.net/Mc92M/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("li.one").on("click", function() {

        $('.content').fadeOut(400);
        if ($('.content').is(':hidden')) {
            $('.content').fadeIn(500);
        } 
    });

    $('.content').hide();
});
```

When you used `.next()` it is targeting the second `li`, not content div so nothing shows or hides. I also removed the `.hide` and `.show` as you already have fade in/out

If you really want to use the `.next()` then you would have to do

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".topnav").on("click", function(e) {

        if( $(e.target).parent().is('li.one') ) {
            $(this).next().toggle();
        }
    });

    $('.content').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your event isn't firing. Just set up a click listener for `ul.topnav` and delegate the event:

> $("ul.topnav").on("click", "li.one", function() { ... });

Then, delete the rest of that nonsense and just use `.toggle()`:

> $('.content').toggle();

## [Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f72ab/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("ul.topnav").on("click", "li.one", function() {
        console.log('clicked!');
        $('.content').toggle();
    });

    $('.content').hide();
});
```

Comment: The click works before, it just didn't target the right element to fade in/out

Comment: Yeah at first i look at the code and thought that click binding was the only issue. Nevermind, the code is working now